# Using the URLconf defined in myproject2.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

Tags: python, django

```
urls.py:
-------
from django.urls import path

from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    path('hello', views.hello, name='hello'),
]

views.py:
--------
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

# create your view here

def hello(request):
    # return HttpResponse('<h1>Hello World</h1>')
    return render(request,'home.html',{'name':"Page"})

Screenshot1: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vfXEf.png

Screenshot2: https://i.stack.imgur.com/igqQe.png
```

Error showing:
Using the URLconf defined in myproject2.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

1.admin/

Comment: Can you add urls.py from your project ?

Comment: Looking at your screenshot you have two `urls.py`. The excerpt in your post should be in `myproject2/urls.py`. Yet the `from . import views` indicates that it's actually in `helloworld/urls.py`. Could you clarify?

Comment: helloworld/urls.py

Answer (score 1):

Common mistake `'/'` is missing in hello url defined:

In your app urls.py correct this mistake:

```
path('hello/', views.hello, name='hello')
```

In your project `urls.py` (which is your `urls.py` file in `myproject2` folder) include your app urls(which is your `urls.py` file in helloworld app) like this:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('hello/', include('helloworld.urls')),
]
```

Also don't forget to add your app to `settings.py` in the list variable installed apps like this with other apps:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'helloworld',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

Before you mess up get the best tutorials to understand how it works!